# Uncaught ReferenceError: DateTime is not defined HTML

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new with HTML / JS
I have an HTML page like this

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const category = document.getElementById("categories").value;
    const message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var now = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.UTC ).toString();
```

But I am getting an error in the console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: DateTime is not defined

I am not sure how to import DateTime in my html file.

Any idea please?

Comment: Do you know the difference between JavaScript and Java? They're not the same thing. At all.

Comment: Nope... I'm usually using python

Comment: use new Date() instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using DateTime, you should be using Date. Note that `new Date().toUTCString()` returns a string. I presume that you are using Firebase Firestore based on the above code. If so, this will be interpreted as a string field, not a timestamp field.

```
const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
const category = document.getElementById("categories").value;
const message = document.getElementById("message").value;
var now = new Date().toUTCString();
```

Comment: I'd like it to be utc based. Does date.now give a utc date ?

Comment: @NicolasRey I have updated my answer to return the UTC Date.

Comment: I have the error Uncaught TypeError: Date.toUTCString is not a function

Comment: @NicolasRey Whoops, should be `new Date().toUTCString()`. Updated the solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to use this:**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.8.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp({
    // Your Firebase configuration here
  });

  const db = firebase.firestore();

  const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  const category = document.getElementById("categories").value;
  const message = document.getElementById("message").value;

  // Get the current server timestamp from Firebase
  const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

  // Create an object with the data you want to store
  const data = {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    category: category,
    message: message,
    timestamp: timestamp
  };

  // Add the data to Firestore
  db.collection("yourCollection").add(data)
    .then(function(docRef) {
      console.log("Document added with ID: ", docRef.id);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    });
</script>
```